# marker on func attribute doesn't seem to work correctly

Tags: python-3.x

I have defined the following decorator:

```
class My_Decorator:

    def __init__(self, marker_list):
        assert isinstance(marker_list, list)
        self.marker_list = marker_list

    def __call__(self, original_class):
        for this_marker in self.marker_list:
            def _method(self):
                print("marker on this func attribute: ", _method.marker)
            _method.marker = this_marker

            setattr(
                    original_class,
                    this_marker,
                    _method
            )

        return original_class


@My_Decorator(['marker1', 'marker2'])
class A: pass
```

I was expecting that the looping inside the callable method will generate different `_method` objects and assign accordingly, with their own corresponding `_method.marker` for each iteration. However, below is what I got:

```
a = A()
>>> A.marker1
<function My_Decorator.__call__.<locals>._method at 0x7fc0ded21bf8>
>>> A.marker2
<function My_Decorator.__call__.<locals>._method at 0x7fc0dec371e0>
>>> A.marker1.marker
'marker1'
>>> A.marker2.marker
'marker2'
>>> a.marker1()
marker on this func attribute:  marker2
>>> a.marker2()
marker on this func attribute:  marker2
```

As we can observe here, the method is stuck with the last marker of the loop.
Could someone help point out why? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Defining a function inside a loop like you did causes *late binding*: the fact that you are calling the function outside the loop, makes it look for the latest `_method` defined.

Enforcing *early binding* will solve your problem:

```
def __call__(self, original_class):
    for this_marker in self.marker_list:
        # set a default value, which is the currently iterated "this_marker"
        def _method(self, this_marker=this_marker):
            # move the attribute setting for "_method" inside the function
            _method.marker = this_marker
            print("marker on this func attribute: ", _method.marker)

        setattr(
                original_class,
                this_marker,
                _method
        )

    return original_class
```

Now:

```
>>> a.marker1()
marker on this func attribute:  marker1
>>> a.marker2()
marker on this func attribute:  marker2
```

Comment: Thanks. But I don't understand why calling from class directly seems to be working. `A.marker1.marker` gives me the correct result, which is `marker1`. Why does bound method look for the last but unbound method locates the correct one for me？

Comment: When you access the method's attribute directly from the class, you get `_method.marker`, which is the marker that you have set. When you call the method from the instantiated object, it might seem like it's accessing it's marker, but it's looking for the latest `this_marker` of the loop, which is `"marker2"`. (you can witness it by printing `this_marker` inside the function).

Comment: Could you explain why you `moved the attribute setting for "_method" inside the function`? Thanks.

Comment: I think we both have hit the black hole of Python.

Comment: I moved it because I want to use the default argument of `this_marker` to ensure *early binding*. If I've kept it outside the function, it would still look for the loop's **latest** `this_marker`.